# ASPX onmouseover

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am not familiar with aspx pages, and the programmer I work with incorporated my JavaScript carousel into an ASPX master page. I want to start the carousel when the mouse hovers over the images, however I can't get the mouseover function to work.

The ASPX function:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  If Not IsPostBack Then
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript([GetType](), "Javascript", "javascript:itemSize(); ", True)
  End If
End Sub
```

As of now the carousel rotates on page load.

Is it possible to do this?

****Note!!! I am very new to programming, so it might be something simple that I am not seeing****

The JavaScript can be found here:
[Java](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?285949-New-to-Developing-need-mouseover-effect)

Comment: Is there any reason to use server side code? If not is better you use plain javascript, but with asp.net can be a little bit tricky

Comment: The pages were built using asp.net. I built the carousel in JavaScript so it can be viewed on an iPad/iPhone etc. In order to incorporate the carousel I had to contact our programmer and this is how she did it.

Comment: Can you access the aspx file or the .master template I would include the script tag there rather than inserting it dinamically

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

Create one function in script tag as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fun()
    {
        alert('hi');
    }
</script>
```

Then use this function with 'img' tag as below:

```
<img src="#" alt="image not found." onmouseover="fun()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `javascript:` at the start of your script.

The text in the 3rd parameter will be placed into a javascript block (as you have `True` as your 4th parameter)... so by having it will cause invalid javascript.

If you check the HTML source after your postback, you'll probably see something like the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  javascript:itemSize();
</script>
```

When what you really want is...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  itemSize();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to add a mouseover function in it? As opposed to the carousel turning when the page loads? I am familiar with HTML not ASPX

Comment: You're talking about two very different things. My answer is dealing with the syntax error that you would receive on the post-back... I have absolutely no knowledge of the "carousel" you mention

Comment: It's in the link. The aspx is calling the script to start on page load

Comment: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?285949-New-to-Developing-need-mouseover-effect